# Problem with matching individual-level data with group-level data

Tags: regression, sampling, causality

I have two datasets in the US:

- Dataset A has 10 million observations of mortgage borrowers with individual features (income, FICO, loan amount, interest rate, etc).
- Dataset B has county-level environmental information (air pollution, water pollution, etc.).

I matched A and B on county information. Now, I want to run a regression of **air pollution** (county-level) with the **mortgage interest rate** (individual-level). From what I understand, one big problem is the individuals' variation within a county could be really large, which could make my estimate biased. But other than, I don't know what else I should address/be aware.

I'd love to hear some insights on this, or some recommended reading materials.

Comment: Could you expand your second paragraph? What do you mean by this? Are you afraid that the country-level data does not catch the individual variability?

Comment: @Tim Yes. My data assumed that air pollution is the same for everyone in a county. That is a very big and somewhat unrealistic assumption.

Comment: Do you have any leads on how air pollution was quantified/aggregated from the original data?

Comment: @Galen Perhaps you meant I should look for a dataset with a lower level than county. Unfortunately, they don't public that.

Comment: @KienHoang No, I just meant that there could be documentation on how the air population data has been aggregated to a country level. I'm musing about modelling the aggregation process done with air pollution  and putting some Bayesian priors on the pollution effects at the individual level. That would be a lot of work and probably wouldn't be a success, so not a good answer to your question. Just musing is all.

Comment: A simplistic approach would be to assume your aggregate air population data are the averages: $\bar {\text{AP}}_{\text{Country}} := \frac{1}{n_{\text{Country}}} \sum_i^{n_{\text{Country}}} \text{AP}_{i,\text{Country}}$ and you could try different [prior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prior_probability) [mixtures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_model) within a country.

Comment: How would large variation within county *bias* your results? It would make them less precise, but how would it introduce bias?

Comment: Hi Peter, can you explain more on that?